# Another four-liner: By myself I can be quite persuasive

Tags: riddle, word

By myself I can be quite persuasive.

With a letter out front, I'm powerful.

With two behind, you'd better act fast.

With three out front, I bring great suffering.

**What is this strong word?**

Comment: I can add more lines/words if this goes on much longer, but I think everyone will find the accepted answer fits *far* better than these tries.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Again! This is starting to get eerie! The word is

> URGE

By myself I can be quite persuasive.

> Urges are certainly persuasive

With a letter out front, I'm powerful.

> SURGE adds one letter and becomes a powerful force (e.g. power surge)

With two behind, you'd better act fast.

> URGENT adds two letters to the back and becomes a force pushing you to move promptly.

With three out front, I bring great suffering.

> SCOURGE adds three letters up front and becomes a plague/calamity that spreads suffering.

I have no related pun this time.

Comment: Keep this up Roland, and people are going to think we're in cahoots

Comment: Sockpuppet alert!!! It's the new Gamow-Martin! No, only kidding :-)

Comment: Wow. Perhaps we're twins, separated at birth, only to find each other 23 years later through a shared predisposition for puzzle solving! May I ask your age? ;)

Comment: Wait, are you 23 years old as well?

Comment: twins confirmed - someone throw a reunion party!

Answer (score 7):

*By myself I can be quite persuasive.*

> An OLD person can be quite persuasive, since age brings wisdom - they should be listened to.

*With a letter out front, I'm powerful.*

> GOLD is power: in the immortal words of Artemis Fowl, *aurum potestas est*.

*With two behind, you'd better act fast.*

> As you get OLDER, you need to act fast before it's too late!

*With three out front, I bring great suffering.*

> A KOBOLD is a wicked mythological creature, which brings suffering to many.

Comment: This works quite well, but I must repeat the puzzlemaker's catchphrase: *My intended solution fits the riddle better. +1*

Answer (score 4):

Is it:

> An Act

By myself I can be quite persuasive.

> A good act (performance) can be persuasive

With a letter out front, I'm powerful.

> A **P**act : When you make a pact with someone, it's a powerful link.

With two behind, you'd better act fast.

> Act**or** , when an actor play, he needs to remember his lines quickly.

With three out front, I bring great suffering.

> An **imp**act : A violent impact can bring suffering

---

*Just realize that there is the word act in one of the line so it's problably the wrong answer*

Comment: I like the first line, and REACT does fit well, but I intended for "two behind" to mean two letters are added at the end.

Comment: Oups, read too fast...

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility (if a bit cheeky)

> Tom

By myself I can be quite persuasive.

> Tom Riddle was very persuasive to those that followed or opposed him.

With a letter out front, I'm powerful.

> *A*tom, the building blocks of the universe, or an atom bomb is very powerful.

With two behind, you'd better act fast.

> Tom*my*, for tommy gun will make you take cover fast.

With three out front, I bring great suffering.

> *Bot*tom - Many a bottom has brought great suffering to those that came after.

Comment: Or, perhaps, being on the bottom *economically* or *socially* can cause you to suffer - no, no, I like yours better.

Comment: Those bottoms are indeed a bit cheeky!

Answer (score 1):

Could it be,

> Imp

By myself I can be quite persuasive.

> Tyrion Lannister in Game of Thrones is an imp and is very persuasive

With a letter out front, I'm powerful.

> A pimp holds a lot of power over his girls

With two behind, you'd better act fast.

> If someone has to impel you to do something you probably don't want to do it, so do it fast

With three out front, I bring great suffering.

> Shrimp. people with shell fish allergies can die from eating a shrimp

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling I am onto it:

By myself I can be quite persuasive.

> WORD - words are very persuasive

With a letter out front, I'm powerful.

> SWORD - swords are mighty objects

This one I'm stuck on.

With three out front, I bring great suffering.

> KEYWORD - this one is a huge stretch, but people often forget their keywords (passwords?)